# JASIG How to get RequestContext in AuthenticationHandler?

Tags: java, authentication, handler, cas, jasig

I'm beginning with JASIG CAS with several Handlers to authenticate. 
I want to login using that type of url : 
https://cas.example.org/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.first-part-url.example.org%2Fservice

My authentication depends on the service parameter : according to the "first-part-url", I call a corresponding ldap service to authenticate my user.

But I don't know how to get that service parameter, I only get Credantials in AuthenticationHandlers.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in the jasig project coding group :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jasig-cas-user/authentication$20handler/jasig-cas-user/olF57mNbtlE/uPWYFZsNAEYJ